# How can I fix the '403 Forbidden' error when using tweepy to access the Twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

## **Something wrong with my tweepy API?**

Been trying to access the twitter API using tweepy, but getting the 403 Forbidden error.

- Tried the TwitterAPI and tweepy which both did not work.
- Researched and followed the youtube tutorials and twitter documentations online which again did not help.
- Made sure that my api & access tokens are correct

Anyone have any suggestions on how there's worked or code? Any suggestion or help would be great. Thanks!!

***Error***

tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden

When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

***My Python code:***

```
import tweepy
import config
import configparser

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=config.BEARER_TOKEN,
                       consumer_key=config.API_KEY,
                       consumer_secret=config.API_SECRET,
                       access_token=config.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                       access_token_secret=config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)


search = "why"
response = client.search_all_tweets(query=search)
```

***Brief background***

- twitter developer account: Essential
- Access level: Free
- Twitter API level: 2
- **I made sure that the app is attached to the project and not a standalone

Answer (score 0):

This is from the official Twitter devloper [website](https://developer.twitter.com/en).

```
For write-only use cases and testing the Twitter API
```

The free account only support posting 1500 tweets per month and does not allow reading tweets. To read tweets there are other paid plans which need to be purchased.