# tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden despite having a developer account (Free plan)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

CODE:

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret )

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
client_id = client.get_me().data.id
response = client.get_users_mentions(client_id)
```

I am getting error:

> When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

However, I have free access which I applied for

Methods like `create_tweet` and `update_status` work but using `get_users_mentions` gives me an error.

Apparently twitter used to have elevated access for stuff like this but they have removed it.
Is the only way I can use get_users_mentions is by purchasing the basic or pro plan paying twitter?

Tried to return user mentions on twitter bot, I expected it to return tweets which mentioned the bots id instead returned error that I don't have a developer account despite having one.

[image: The bot is under a project]

Comment: The error message says that your app must be attached to a project.  Is it?

Comment: Yes it is. I will update the question to show a picture of the project

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76297656/how-can-i-fix-the-403-forbidden-error-when-using-tweepy-to-access-the-twitter?rq=2

Free API can only be used to write tweets and not use them :(